# How does variable hoisting work in this JS example: if(true){...}

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, functional-programming, hoisting

I came across this sample code snippet regarding functional scoping vs. block scoping, but I'm not certain how it works:

```
(function () {
  if (true) {
    var x = true;
    console.log("Is 'x' available inside the block? " + x);
  }
  console.log("Is 'x' available outside the block? " + x);
})();
```

Initially, I thought that the conditional is checking to see if the value of the declared variable, x, is true and b/c of variable hoisting it's possible to have the conditional abbreviated to 'if(true)' rather than 'if(x==true)'.

However, if you change the value of x so that x=false, the code block w/in the conditional still executes and both console logs are triggered with the value of x as 'false'. Shouldn't it only execute the console log that is outside of the conditional statement?

If x=true, and the conditional is changed to 'if(false)', then only the console log outside of the conditional executes, but.. the value of x is undefined. If the variable has functional scope and it's hoisted, then shouldn't the outer console log execute and the value of x=false?

Thanks!

Comment: Hoisting doesn't affect scope as seen by you program;  the semantics remain unchanged. The hoisted x is not the same variable as x in the outer scope even after hoisting.

Answer (score 1):

The variable initialization (`var x`) is always hoisted to the function scope, but the assignment is not. For this reason, it's considered good practice to initialize all your variables at the top of the function in which they are used. (note: in ES6, you can use the [block-scoped `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var`)

In your example, regardless of the conditional, the variable `x` is in scope for the entire function. Also worth noting, you've hardcoded the condition (`if (true)`); if you want to branch on the value of `x`, you'll need `if (x)`.

Here's some examples to illustrate hoisting:

Uninitialized (throws `ReferenceError: x is not defined`):

```js
    (function() { console.log(x) })()
```

Initialized in unreachable code (returns `undefined`):

```js
(function() {
  if (false) {
    var x
  }
  console.log(x)
})()
```

Initialized in doubly-unreachable code (returns `undefined`!!):

```js
(function() {
  return console.log(x)
  if (false) {
    var x
  }
})()
```

Comment: I think I follow what you mean regarding variable initialization vs. assignment.. if the code is rewritten the following way it seems to follow the better practice.
(function () {
var x; 
  if (true) {
    x = true;
    console.log("... " + x);  //executes, x=true
  }
  console.log("... " + x);   //executes, x=true
})();
.. but
(function () {
var x; 
  if (true) {
    x = false;
    console.log("... " + x);  // still executes, x=false (unexpected)
  }
  console.log("... " + x);   // executes, x=false (expected)
})();

What then, is the conditional evaluating, if not the value of 'x'?

Comment: In all of your examples, you're hardcoding the condition `if (true)`, and therefore guaranteeing that the block is evaluated, regardless of the value of `x`. If updated my answer to note this.

Answer (score 0):

Block scope does not exist in Javascript, (unless you use a `let` statement) only function scope applies to variables declared with a `var` statement. When the function is executed,  there is space allocated for the variable x, which is available anywhere within that function, however, the assignment only occurs where the statement is in the function. If the condition is falsey, the assignment never occurs. x will have the value `undefined` anywhere before the assignment or if the assignment doesn't happen.